# Apache POI vs JS XLS - What's the best for an Excel Sheet driven application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-poi, ui-grid, js-xlsx

I'm developing an Excel Sheet driven application.

All the data must be retrieved from an specific and default Excel Sheet that will contain new rows and alterations in existing rows. I need to merge specific columns with the existing data, and preserving the other columns.

The basic functions are:

- **Import table and merge with existing data (data that is already in database).**
- **Edit certain columns of this existing data in a grid/table view.**

I need to import an .xlsx file (not .csv). My frontend is in AngularJS and backend with Java.

With AngularJS (JavaScript), I can use the **JS XLSX library**.

With Java, I can use **Apache POI**.

What's the best approach? And what good materials/examples can you recommend?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Does the "merging columns" require inserting, shifting, or deleting columns? POI has row shift, copy, and delete support, but lacks support for columns. How much of Excel do you plan on implementing in your grid/table view? Number formatting, data types, formula parsing and evaluation, auto-fill dragging, conditional formatting, pivot tables, etc? The ongoing feature requests could provide decades of job security.